# angular 10 bootstrap - display 5 columns in a row in the *ngfor loop

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular10

I want to display 5 columns in a row. 6 columns are rendering if I use col-2, 4 columns are rendering if I use col-3. How can I display 5 columns?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-2"  *ngFor="let control of controls; let i=index;">
           {{contol.data}}
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use col-auto class which will automatically adjust columns based on screen size or you can create your own col class for 5 columns like below :

```
   .col {
      flex: 0 0 20%;
      max-width: 20%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use column class **col** instead of **col-2**. Please have a look to the following code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col"  *ngFor="let control of controls; let i=index;">
        {{contol.data}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you. Thank you.